# Mediatemple: Using another IP address as mail server

Tags: email-server, mediatemple, virtualization

I have a mediatemple dv server and it has 3 IP addresses. Currently, it uses one of the IP addresses for the mail server. How do I use another IP address? Is it possible to use two of the IP addresses for the mail server?

Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by using 2 IP addresses for 1 mail server?

Answer (score 0):

I work for (mt) Media Temple. Technically you could use a custom configuration of your vhosts to use 2 IP's for email, but it'd be a bit of a pain. I echo Sam's question of why you are wanting to do this?

Comment: Using two IP addresses is unnecessary. I was just wondering if it's possible. Truth is I only need to change the IP address for my mail server. How do I do this? TIA